# Laravel 4 Validator - Validate if post belongs to category that belongs to current user

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I have 3 tables, "links", "links_categories" and "users" and I want allow the user to delete the links, but I need to check if the link belongs to the user, here's how my tables are working :

```
links
----------------
id
category_id

links_categories
----------------
id
user_id

users
----------------
id
```

I defined my relationships like that :

```
class Link extends Eloquent
{
    public function category()
    {
        return ($this->belongsTo('LinkCategory', 'category_id', 'id')->with('categoryType'));
    }
}

class LinkCategory extends Eloquent
{
    public function links()
    {
        return ($this->hasMany('Link', 'category_id'));
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return ($this->belongsTo('User'));
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
    public function linkCategories()
    {
        return ($this->hasMany('LinkCategory')->with('links', 'categoryType'));
    }
}
```

Is their an easy way to validate the fact that a link belongs to a user ?

Thanks.

Comment: try something like this..

`$idsOfLinkCategories = $user->linkCategories()->lists('category_id');

return in_array($linkCategoryId,$idsOfLinkCategories);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit deletion up-front—say, in a list of links, you want to only present the user with a "delete" button next to the links that belong to them—then you can check the `user_id` against the `Auth::user()->id` when displaying links. For each link, the `user_id` is accessible at `$link->category->user_id`, which you can eager load using `->with('category')` when you obtain your list of links.

Alternatively (or, in addition) you can set up a model event listener that will perform this validation whenever a link is deleted. In your `links` model, set up your listener:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($link)
    {
        if ($link->category->user_id != Auth::user()->id) {
            Session::flash('error', 'delete_unauthorized');
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

The link's `deleting` listener will check if the user is authorized to delete the link, and if not, it will return `false` (which prevents the delete from occurring) and send an error code to the next request, which you can handle as you see fit, if you need to give feedback to the user. A good walkthrough of using model events is at http://driesvints.com/blog/using-laravel-4-model-events.

You can extend this functionality using model observers; see http://matthewhailwood.co.nz/laravel-model-validation-using-observers/